# Can I scale AWS Spot Instances with CloudWatch alarms?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

I need to do some server-side manipulation of images. Typically these images are either uploaded or imported into our systems at some nominal level, but occasionally a customer will be added that has a very large volume of images that need to be processed at once. While these do need to be processed in a reasonable amount of time, working these larger jobs cheaply is more important than doing them quickly.

As such, I'd like to use AWS Spot Instances for this to keep costs as low as possible, keeping the max bid price relatively fixed (manually change it when needed) while moving the desired number of instances up and down as the number of messages in the queue fluctuates.

I am very new to AWS, but here is what I've tried so far (all via the AWS Management Consoles)...

1. Create an SQS queue to hold the incoming image processing task messages
2. Create two CloudWatch alarms

   - **ScaleIn**, which alerts when **ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible** <= 1 for 300 seconds
   - **ScaleOut**, which alerts when **ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible** > 1 for 300 seconds
3. Create a Launch Configuration that is setup to pay some max bid amount for Spot Instances
4. Create an Auto Scaling Group that uses my Launch Configuration to auto scale between 0 and n instances.
5. Add two Scaling Policies to the Auto Scaling Group

   - **Decrease Group Size**, which removes 1 instance when the **ScaleIn** alarm fires
   - **Increase Group Size**, which adds 1 instance when the **ScaleOut** alarm fires

I then use the SQS Management Console to manually add a couple of test messages. The alarms seem to be firing, but the following message shows up repeatedly in the Auto Scaling Group's Scaling History tab...

```
Description: Description Placing Spot instance request. Status Reason: Max spot instance count exceeded. Placing Spot instance request failed.
Cause: Cause At 2014-08-12T23:12:51Z a difference between desired and actual capacity changing the desired capacity, increasing the capacity from 0 to 1.
```

Can the max number of Spot Instances be controlled in an Auto Scaling Group in this manner? If I follow the same procedure but instead create a regular EC2 Auto Scaling Group/Launch Config (not spot instances), the number of instances in the group grows and shrinks as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this AWS doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-spot-limits.html), there's a maximum number of spot instances you can have in one region:

> ### Spot Request Limits
>
> By default, you are limited to **a total of 5 Spot Instance requests in a region**. New AWS accounts might have lower limits. Currently, the instance types T2, I2, and HS1 are not available on Spot. Also, some instance types are not offered in all regions. (For information about instance types, see Instance Types.)

It sounds like you're bumping into that - you'll need to fill out [this form](https://aws.amazon.com/support/createCase?serviceLimitIncreaseType=ec2-instances&type=service_limit_increase) to request that the limit be increased.

Comment: Thanks @Undo. I had put in a request for the limit increase just before I posted to SO, but they haven't yet responded. We'll see what they say and hopefully that fixes it. What is strange is that I set the same process up in a second region late yesterday, and the error appeared with the very first Spot request.

Comment: It seems to be working now. My request to increase the spot request limit is now marked as "Work-in-Progress" and the auto scaling group is increasing/decreasing the desired number of spot instances as expected. I suspect the increased the limit. Thanks for help, @Undo.